# Is there a reason for this old version of 7-zip on Debian 10.2?

Tags: debian, p7zip

Is there a reason why the [stable](https://packages.debian.org/buster/p7zip-full) and even [testing](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/p7zip-full) distributions of Debian still use an old version of [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) ?

The current stable version of 7-zip is 19.00 and Debian Buster and Bullseye use 16.02

Comment: The packages.debian.org pages you linked include a mailto: link of the package maintainer Robert Luberda. He would be the right person to answer this question. Have you tried contacting him?

Comment: @telcoM no need to bother Robert in this instance, see my answer...

Comment: The native (Windows) version of 7-zip had security vulnerability with the self-extracting archives it produces, so they updated it in 2019. This vulnerability is not present in p7zip, obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason: Debian packages [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), the POSIX port of 7-zip, and [the latest release of p7zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/) is 16.02.

[This forum thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/discussion/383043/thread/fa143cf2/) provides background on the relationship between 7-zip and p7zip, and the lack of updates to the latter.